# find the ranked values per different criteria

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset of cars that consists of Car_code, customer rent code, Rent Dateas below table :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([['x','iii-2019-10-16','18/04/2019'],
                   ['x','iii-2019-10-16','21/07/2019'],
                   ['x','iii-2019-10-16','12/09/2019'],
                   ['x','zzz-2020-10-25','12/04/2022'],
                   ['y','qqq-2018-05-28','10/12/2017'], 
                   ['y','qqq-2018-05-28','15/02/2018'],
                   ['y','ooo-2019-11-22','30/05/2019'],
                   ['y','rrr-16-12-2020','16/12/2020'],
                   ['z','ppt-2019-12-03','07/02/2018'],
                   ['z','ttt-2019-12-03','28/05/2019'],
                   ['z','ttt-2019-12-03','09/09/2019'],
                   ['z','ttt-2019-12-03','30/09/2019']
                  
                  ],
                  columns=['Car_code','customer_rent_code','Rent_Date'])
df
```

I need to create new two columns:

1- rank the table by 'Car_code', then 'customer_rent_code' , then 'Rent_Date'

2- the first new column is 'Rent_rank' which represents the rank of the rent per car per customer rent code so for example car x the first 3 rents will take the rank 1 then the fourth one will take rank 2

3- the second column is 'Rent_rank_per_customer' which represents the rank of the rent within the same 'customer_rent_code' so the values for car x will be (1,2,3,1)

the expected result will be the below:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With 2 groupings and transformation:

```
df['Rent_rank_per_customer'] = (df.groupby(['Car_code', 'customer_rent_code'])['customer_rent_code']
                                .transform(lambda x: x.rank(method='first')))
df['Rent_rank'] = df.groupby('Car_code')['customer_rent_code'].transform(lambda x: x.factorize()[0] + 1)
```

---

```
   Car_code customer_rent_code   Rent_Date  Rent_rank_per_customer  Rent_rank
0         x     iii-2019-10-16  18/04/2019                     1.0          1
1         x     iii-2019-10-16  21/07/2019                     2.0          1
2         x     iii-2019-10-16  12/09/2019                     3.0          1
3         x     zzz-2020-10-25  12/04/2022                     1.0          2
4         y     qqq-2018-05-28  10/12/2017                     1.0          1
5         y     qqq-2018-05-28  15/02/2018                     2.0          1
6         y     ooo-2019-11-22  30/05/2019                     1.0          2
7         y     rrr-16-12-2020  16/12/2020                     1.0          3
8         z     ppt-2019-12-03  07/02/2018                     1.0          1
9         z     ttt-2019-12-03  28/05/2019                     1.0          2
10        z     ttt-2019-12-03  09/09/2019                     2.0          2
11        z     ttt-2019-12-03  30/09/2019                     3.0          2
```

Comment: but you need to add the below to make sure that the items sort:
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Rent_Date"],dayfirst=True)

df = df.sort_values(by=['Car_code','Date'],ascending=[True,True])

Answer (score 0):

```
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Rent_Date"],dayfirst=True)

df = df.sort_values(by=['Car_code','Date'],ascending=[True,True])

df['Rent_rank_per_customer'] = df.groupby(["Car_code","customer_rent_code"]).Date.rank(method='dense')

items = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Car_code','customer_rent_code'],keep='first').set_index(['Car_code','customer_rent_code']).index

mapping_dict = dict(zip(items, range(1, len(items) + 1)))
df['Rent_rank'] = df.set_index(['Car_code','customer_rent_code']).index.map(mapping_dict)
df['Rent_rank'] = df.Rent_rank - df.groupby('Car_code').transform('min').Rent_rank + 1
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).