# How to find the date difference in dataframe and exclude the first item

Tags: pandas

I have the below dataset:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['x','iii-2019-10-16','18/07/2019'],
                   ['x','iii-2019-10-16','21/04/2019'],
                   ['x','iii-2019-10-16','12/09/2019'],
                   ['x','zzz-2020-10-25','12/04/2022'],
                   ['y','qqq-2018-05-28','10/12/2020'], 
                   ['y','qqq-2018-05-28','15/02/2018'],
                   ['y','ooo-2019-11-22','30/05/2019'],
                   ['y','rrr-16-12-2020','16/12/2020'],
                   ['z','ppt-2019-12-03','07/02/2018'],
                   ['z','ttt-2019-12-03','28/05/2019'],
                   ['z','ttt-2019-12-03','09/09/2019'],
                   ['z','ttt-2019-12-03','30/09/2019']
                  ],
                  columns=['Car_code','customer_rent_code','Rent_Date'])
```

I need to find the date difference in days between entries per car_code so for example car x but the first date per car will be empty the expected result will be:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With date difference within a group:

```
df['Rent_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Rent_Date'], dayfirst=True)
df['Date diff'] = df.groupby('Car_code')['Rent_Date'].diff().abs().dt.days
```

---

```
   Car_code customer_rent_code  Rent_Date  Date diff
0         x     iii-2019-10-16 2019-07-18        NaN
1         x     iii-2019-10-16 2019-04-21       88.0
2         x     iii-2019-10-16 2019-09-12      144.0
3         x     zzz-2020-10-25 2022-04-12      943.0
4         y     qqq-2018-05-28 2020-12-10        NaN
5         y     qqq-2018-05-28 2018-02-15     1029.0
6         y     ooo-2019-11-22 2019-05-30      469.0
7         y     rrr-16-12-2020 2020-12-16      566.0
8         z     ppt-2019-12-03 2018-02-07        NaN
9         z     ttt-2019-12-03 2019-05-28      475.0
10        z     ttt-2019-12-03 2019-09-09      104.0
11        z     ttt-2019-12-03 2019-09-30       21.0
```

Comment: If you want to keep the original date format, you can also use `pd.to_datetime(df['Rent_Date'], dayfirst=True).groupby(df['Car_code']).diff().abs().dt.days` directly ;) +1

Comment: @mozway, thanks, I think the OP expects the converted dates (when viewed from the previous https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76147344/find-the-ranked-values-per-different-criteria/76147866?noredirect=1#comment134297313_76147866)